# Partition with possibly empty elements

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

Is there a name for $(A_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of subsets of $E$ such that the $A_i$'s don't intersect each other and the union of the $A_i$'s equals $E$?

Comment: The title of your question sounds like a pretty good candidate for a name

Comment: I would prefer a quasi partition (at least in French)

Comment: What is a context? How adding some emptysets to a partition can be useful?

Comment: No particular context.

Comment: It is called a partition.  If some of the sets are empty, ignore them.

Comment: "Pairwise disjoint and cover $E$" is a phrasing that would probably work, as long as your audience is familiar with that use of the word "cover".